# Как получить отсортированные данные по алфавиту с ResultSet? Java

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, запрос

```
HashSet<String> user = new HashSet<String>();
String SQL = "SELECT distinct userid FROM sch.stutents order by userid ASC";
ResultSet resultSet = connection.createStatement().executeQuery(SQL);
   while (resultSet.next()) {
       user.add(resultSet.getString("userid"));
   }
```

Если тянуть данные с помощью `pgAdmin III`, то возвращаются верно отсортированные данные.
Но при использовании `ResultSet` данные явно сортируются не по полю!

Как получить отсортированный результат с БД используя `ResultSet`?

Comment: Как вы определили, что результат не отсортирован? Если проверяете хэш-таблицу `user`, то она не гарантирует порядок добавляемых данных.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HashSet** не гарантирует упорядоченности элементов, поскольку процесс хеширования сам по себе обычно не порождает сортированных наборов. Если вам нужны сортированные наборы, то лучшим выбором может быть другой тип коллекций, такой как класс `TreeSet`.

**TreeSet** - коллекция, которая хранит свои элементы в виде упорядоченного по значениям дерева. `TreeSet` инкапсулирует в себе `TreeMap`, который в свою очередь использует сбалансированное бинарное красно-черное дерево для хранения элементов.

А для обратной сортировки в `TreeSet` можно воспользоваться `descendingSet()`, что-то типа: `user = (TreeSet)user.descendingSet();`

Comment: SQL верный и тянет данные тоже верно, а ошибка была просто в хэш-функции!

И с того что я прочитал, могу сделать выводы, что с помощью `ResultSet ` нельзя получить отсортированне данные, хотя по сути он здесь был и ни при чем.

У меня был еще случай когда надо было использовать `LinkedHashSet`.

Comment: @Giovanni `ResultSet` не причем, да. Этот класс представляет результирующий набор базы данных. Он обеспечивает приложению построчный доступ к результатам запросов в базе данных. Во время обработки запроса `ResultSet` поддерживает указатель на текущую обрабатываемую строку. Приложение последовательно перемещается по результатам, пока они не будут все обработаны или не будет закрыт `ResultSet`...Важно куда вы складируете. Это может быть `set`, а может быть и `list` или `hashmap` и т.д.Прост важно знать в чем их отличие....Можт если б вы в `list` складировали - все было бы сразу так, как задумали